# Can not install PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg library in laravel with composer

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, ffmpeg, composer-php

I want to install php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg library in my app but it keeps giving me this error :

```
composer require php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg
Using version ^0.11.1 for php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg v0.11.1-pl-1
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/console v4.0.9
    - Installation request for php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg ^0.11.1 -> satisfiable by php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg[v0.11.1, v0.11.1-pl-1].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.0.9
    - Conclusion: don't install alchemy/binary-driver 1.6.0|remove symfony/process v4.0.9|install symfony/process 2.0.4|install symfony/process 2.0.5|install symfony/process 2.0.6|install symfony/process 2.0.7|install symfony/process 2.0.x-dev|install symfony/process 2.1.x-dev|install symfony/process 2.2.x-dev|install symfony/process 2.3.x-dev|install symfony/process 2.4.x-dev|install symfony/process 2.5.x-dev|install symfony/process 2.6.x-dev|install symfony/process 2.7.x-dev|install symfony/process 2.8.x-dev|install symfony/process 3.0.x-dev|install symfony/process 3.1.x-dev|install symfony/process 3.2.x-dev|install symfony/process v2.0.10|install symfony/process v2.0.12|install symfony/process v2.0.13|install symfony/process v2.0.14|install symfony/process v2.0.15|install symfony/process v2.0.16|install symfony/process v2.0.17|install symfony/process v2.0.18|install symfony/process v2.0.19|install symfony/process v2.0.20|install symfony/process v2.0.21|install symfony/process v2.0.22|install symfony/process v2.0.23|install symfony/process v2.0.24|install symfony/process v2.0.25|install symfony/process v2.0.9|install symfony/process v2.1.0|install symfony/process v2.1.1|install symfony/process v2.1.10|install symfony/process v2.1.11|install symfony/process v2.1.12|install symfony/process v2.1.13|install symfony/process v2.1.2|install symfony/process v2.1.3|install symfony/process v2.1.4|install symfony/process v2.1.5|install symfony/process v2.1.6|install symfony/process v2.1.7|install symfony/process v2.1.8|install symfony/process v2.1.9|install symfony/process v2.2.0|install symfony/process v2.2.1|install symfony/process v2.2.10|install symfony/process v2.2.11|install symfony/process v2.2.2|install symfony/process v2.2.3|install symfony/process v2.2.4|install symfony/process v2.2.5|install symfony/process v2.2.6|install symfony/process v2.2.7|install symfony/process v2.2.8|install symfony/process v2.2.9|install symfony/process v2.3.0|install symfony/process v2.3.1|install symfony/process v2.3.10|install symfony/process v2.3.11|install symfony/process v2.3.12|install symfony/process v2.3.13|install symfony/process v2.3.14|install symfony/process v2.3.15|install symfony/process v2.3.16|install symfony/process v2.3.17|install symfony/process v2.3.18|install symfony/process v2.3.19|install symfony/process v2.3.2|install symfony/process v2.3.20|install symfony/process v2.3.21|install symfony/process v2.3.22|install symfony/process v2.3.23|install symfony/process v2.3.24|install symfony/process v2.3.25|install symfony/process v2.3.26|install symfony/process v2.3.27|install symfony/process v2.3.28|install symfony/process v2.3.29|install symfony/process v2.3.3|install symfony/process v2.3.30|install symfony/process v2.3.31|install symfony/process v2.3.32|install symfony/process v2.3.33|install symfony/process v2.3.34|install symfony/process v2.3.35|install symfony/process v2.3.36|install symfony/process v2.3.37|install symfony/process v2.3.38|install symfony/process v2.3.39|install symfony/process v2.3.4|install symfony/process v2.3.40|install symfony/process v2.3.41|install symfony/process v2.3.42|install symfony/process v2.3.5|install symfony/process v2.3.6|install symfony/process v2.3.7|install symfony/process v2.3.8|install symfony/process v2.3.9|install symfony/process v2.4.0|install symfony/process v2.4.0-BETA1|install symfony/process v2.4.0-BETA2|install symfony/process v2.4.0-RC1|install symfony/process v2.4.1|install symfony/process v2.4.10|install symfony/process v2.4.2|install symfony/process v2.4.3|install symfony/process v2.4.4|install symfony/process v2.4.5|install symfony/process v2.4.6|install symfony/process v2.4.7|install symfony/process v2.4.8|install symfony/process v2.4.9|install symfony/process v2.5.0|install symfony/process v2.5.0-BETA1|install symfony/process v2.5.0-BETA2|install symfony/process v2.5.0-RC1|install symfony/process v2.5.1|install symfony/process v2.5.10|install symfony/process v2.5.11|install symfony/process v2.5.12|install symfony/process v2.5.2|install symfony/process v2.5.3|install symfony/process v2.5.4|install symfony/process v2.5.5|install symfony/process v2.5.6|install symfony/process v2.5.7|install symfony/process v2.5.8|install symfony/process v2.5.9|install symfony/process v2.6.0|install symfony/process v2.6.0-BETA1|install symfony/process v2.6.0-BETA2|install symfony/process v2.6.1|install symfony/process v2.6.10|install symfony/process v2.6.11|install symfony/process v2.6.12|install symfony/process v2.6.13|install symfony/process v2.6.2|install symfony/process v2.6.3|install symfony/process v2.6.4|install symfony/process v2.6.5|install symfony/process v2.6.6|install symfony/process v2.6.7|install symfony/process v2.6.8|install symfony/process v2.6.9|install symfony/process v2.7.0|install symfony/process v2.7.0-BETA1|install symfony/process v2.7.0-BETA2|install symfony/process v2.7.1|install symfony/process v2.7.10|install symfony/process v2.7.11|install symfony/process v2.7.12|install symfony/process v2.7.13|install symfony/process v2.7.14|install symfony/process v2.7.15|install symfony/process v2.7.16|install symfony/process v2.7.17|install symfony/process v2.7.18|install symfony/process v2.7.19|install symfony/process v2.7.2|install symfony/process v2.7.20|install symfony/process v2.7.21|install symfony/process v2.7.22|install symfony/process v2.7.23|install symfony/process v2.7.24|install symfony/process v2.7.25|install symfony/process v2.7.26|install symfony/process v2.7.27|install symfony/process v2.7.28|install symfony/process v2.7.29|install symfony/process v2.7.3|install symfony/process v2.7.30|install symfony/process v2.7.31|install symfony/process v2.7.32|install symfony/process v2.7.33|install symfony/process v2.7.34|install symfony/process v2.7.35|install symfony/process v2.7.36|install symfony/process v2.7.37|install symfony/process v2.7.38|install symfony/process v2.7.39|install symfony/process v2.7.4|install symfony/process v2.7.40|install symfony/process v2.7.41|install symfony/process v2.7.42|install symfony/process v2.7.43|install symfony/process v2.7.44|install symfony/process v2.7.45|install symfony/process v2.7.46|install symfony/process v2.7.5|install symfony/process v2.7.6|install symfony/process v2.7.7|install symfony/process v2.7.8|install symfony/process v2.7.9|install symfony/process v2.8.0|install symfony/process v2.8.0-BETA1|install symfony/process v2.8.1|install symfony/process v2.8.10|install symfony/process v2.8.11|install symfony/process v2.8.12|install symfony/process v2.8.13|install symfony/process v2.8.14|install symfony/process v2.8.15|install symfony/process v2.8.16|install symfony/process v2.8.17|install symfony/process v2.8.18|install symfony/process v2.8.19|install symfony/process v2.8.2|install symfony/process v2.8.20|install symfony/process v2.8.21|install symfony/process v2.8.22|install symfony/process v2.8.23|install symfony/process v2.8.24|install symfony/process v2.8.25|install symfony/process v2.8.26|install symfony/process v2.8.27|install symfony/process v2.8.28|install symfony/process v2.8.29|install symfony/process v2.8.3|install symfony/process v2.8.30|install symfony/process v2.8.31|install symfony/process v2.8.32|install symfony/process v2.8.33|install symfony/process v2.8.34|install symfony/process v2.8.35|install symfony/process v2.8.36|install symfony/process v2.8.37|install symfony/process v2.8.38|install symfony/process v2.8.39|install symfony/process v2.8.4|install symfony/process v2.8.5|install symfony/process v2.8.6|install symfony/process v2.8.7|install symfony/process v2.8.8|install symfony/process v2.8.9|install symfony/process v3.0.0|install symfony/process v3.0.0-BETA1|install symfony/process v3.0.1|install symfony/process v3.0.2|install symfony/process v3.0.3|install symfony/process v3.0.4|install symfony/process v3.0.5|install symfony/process v3.0.6|install symfony/process v3.0.7|install symfony/process v3.0.8|install symfony/process v3.0.9|install symfony/process v3.1.0|install symfony/process v3.1.0-BETA1|install symfony/process v3.1.0-RC1|install symfony/process v3.1.1|install symfony/process v3.1.10|install symfony/process v3.1.2|install symfony/process v3.1.3|install symfony/process v3.1.4|install symfony/process v3.1.5|install symfony/process v3.1.6|install symfony/process v3.1.7|install symfony/process v3.1.8|install symfony/process v3.1.9|install symfony/process v3.2.0|install symfony/process v3.2.0-BETA1|install symfony/process v3.2.0-RC1|install symfony/process v3.2.0-RC2|install symfony/process v3.2.1|install symfony/process v3.2.10|install symfony/process v3.2.11|install symfony/process v3.2.12|install symfony/process v3.2.13|install symfony/process v3.2.14|install symfony/process v3.2.2|install symfony/process v3.2.3|install symfony/process v3.2.4|install symfony/process v3.2.5|install symfony/process v3.2.6|install symfony/process v3.2.7|install symfony/process v3.2.8|install symfony/process v3.2.9
    - Conclusion: don't install alchemy/binary-driver 1.6.0|don't install symfony/process v4.0.9|install symfony/process 2.0.4|install symfony/process 2.0.5|install symfony/process 2.0.6|install symfony/process 2.0.7|install symfony/process 2.0.x-dev|install symfony/process 2.1.x-dev|install symfony/process 2.2.x-dev|install symfony/process 2.3.x-dev|install symfony/process 2.4.x-dev|install symfony/process 2.5.x-dev|install symfony/process 2.6.x-dev|install symfony/process 2.7.x-dev|install symfony/process 2.8.x-dev|install symfony/process 3.0.x-dev|install symfony/process 3.1.x-dev|install symfony/process 3.2.x-dev|install symfony/process v2.0.10|install symfony/process v2.0.12|install symfony/process v2.0.13|install symfony/process v2.0.14|install symfony/process v2.0.15|install symfony/process v2.0.16|install symfony/process v2.0.17|install symfony/process v2.0.18|install symfony/process v2.0.19|install symfony/process v2.0.20|install symfony/process v2.0.21|install symfony/process v2.0.22|install symfony/process v2.0.23|install symfony/process v2.0.24|install symfony/process v2.0.25|install symfony/process v2.0.9|install symfony/process v2.1.0|install symfony/process v2.1.1|install symfony/process v2.1.10|install symfony/process v2.1.11|install symfony/process v2.1.12|install symfony/process v2.1.13|install symfony/process v2.1.2|install symfony/process v2.1.3|install symfony/process v2.1.4|install symfony/process v2.1.5|install symfony/process v2.1.6|install symfony/process v2.1.7|install symfony/process v2.1.8|install symfony/process v2.1.9|install symfony/process v2.2.0|install symfony/process v2.2.1|install symfony/process v2.2.10|install symfony/process v2.2.11|install symfony/process v2.2.2|install symfony/process v2.2.3|install symfony/process v2.2.4|install symfony/process v2.2.5|install symfony/process v2.2.6|install symfony/process v2.2.7|install symfony/process v2.2.8|install symfony/process v2.2.9|install symfony/process v2.3.0|install symfony/process v2.3.1|install symfony/process v2.3.10|install symfony/process v2.3.11|install symfony/process v2.3.12|install symfony/process v2.3.13|install symfony/process v2.3.14|install symfony/process v2.3.15|install symfony/process v2.3.16|install symfony/process v2.3.17|install symfony/process v2.3.18|install symfony/process v2.3.19|install symfony/process v2.3.2|install symfony/process v2.3.20|install symfony/process v2.3.21|install symfony/process v2.3.22|install symfony/process v2.3.23|install symfony/process v2.3.24|install symfony/process v2.3.25|install symfony/process v2.3.26|install symfony/process v2.3.27|install symfony/process v2.3.28|install symfony/process v2.3.29|install symfony/process v2.3.3|install symfony/process v2.3.30|install symfony/process v2.3.31|install symfony/process v2.3.32|install symfony/process v2.3.33|install symfony/process v2.3.34|install symfony/process v2.3.35|install symfony/process v2.3.36|install symfony/process v2.3.37|install symfony/process v2.3.38|install symfony/process v2.3.39|install symfony/process v2.3.4|install symfony/process v2.3.40|install symfony/process v2.3.41|install symfony/process v2.3.42|install symfony/process v2.3.5|install symfony/process v2.3.6|install symfony/process v2.3.7|install symfony/process v2.3.8|install symfony/process v2.3.9|install symfony/process v2.4.0|install symfony/process v2.4.0-BETA1|install symfony/process v2.4.0-BETA2|install symfony/process v2.4.0-RC1|install symfony/process v2.4.1|install symfony/process v2.4.10|install symfony/process v2.4.2|install symfony/process v2.4.3|install symfony/process v2.4.4|install symfony/process v2.4.5|install symfony/process v2.4.6|install symfony/process v2.4.7|install symfony/process v2.4.8|install symfony/process v2.4.9|install symfony/process v2.5.0|install symfony/process v2.5.0-BETA1|install symfony/process v2.5.0-BETA2|install symfony/process v2.5.0-RC1|install symfony/process v2.5.1|install symfony/process v2.5.10|install symfony/process v2.5.11|install symfony/process v2.5.12|install symfony/process v2.5.2|install symfony/process v2.5.3|install symfony/process v2.5.4|install symfony/process v2.5.5|install symfony/process v2.5.6|install symfony/process v2.5.7|install symfony/process v2.5.8|install symfony/process v2.5.9|install symfony/process v2.6.0|install symfony/process v2.6.0-BETA1|install symfony/process v2.6.0-BETA2|install symfony/process v2.6.1|install symfony/process v2.6.10|install symfony/process v2.6.11|install symfony/process v2.6.12|install symfony/process v2.6.13|install symfony/process v2.6.2|install symfony/process v2.6.3|install symfony/process v2.6.4|install symfony/process v2.6.5|install symfony/process v2.6.6|install symfony/process v2.6.7|install symfony/process v2.6.8|install symfony/process v2.6.9|install symfony/process v2.7.0|install symfony/process v2.7.0-BETA1|install symfony/process v2.7.0-BETA2|install symfony/process v2.7.1|install symfony/process v2.7.10|install symfony/process v2.7.11|install symfony/process v2.7.12|install symfony/process v2.7.13|install symfony/process v2.7.14|install symfony/process v2.7.15|install symfony/process v2.7.16|install symfony/process v2.7.17|install symfony/process v2.7.18|install symfony/process v2.7.19|install symfony/process v2.7.2|install symfony/process v2.7.20|install symfony/process v2.7.21|install symfony/process v2.7.22|install symfony/process v2.7.23|install symfony/process v2.7.24|install symfony/process v2.7.25|install symfony/process v2.7.26|install symfony/process v2.7.27|install symfony/process v2.7.28|install symfony/process v2.7.29|install symfony/process v2.7.3|install symfony/process v2.7.30|install symfony/process v2.7.31|install symfony/process v2.7.32|install symfony/process v2.7.33|install symfony/process v2.7.34|install symfony/process v2.7.35|install symfony/process v2.7.36|install symfony/process v2.7.37|install symfony/process v2.7.38|install symfony/process v2.7.39|install symfony/process v2.7.4|install symfony/process v2.7.40|install symfony/process v2.7.41|install symfony/process v2.7.42|install symfony/process v2.7.43|install symfony/process v2.7.44|install symfony/process v2.7.45|install symfony/process v2.7.46|install symfony/process v2.7.5|install symfony/process v2.7.6|install symfony/process v2.7.7|install symfony/process v2.7.8|install symfony/process v2.7.9|install symfony/process v2.8.0|install symfony/process v2.8.0-BETA1|install symfony/process v2.8.1|install symfony/process v2.8.10|install symfony/process v2.8.11|install symfony/process v2.8.12|install symfony/process v2.8.13|install symfony/process v2.8.14|install symfony/process v2.8.15|install symfony/process v2.8.16|install symfony/process v2.8.17|install symfony/process v2.8.18|install symfony/process v2.8.19|install symfony/process v2.8.2|install symfony/process v2.8.20|install symfony/process v2.8.21|install symfony/process v2.8.22|install symfony/process v2.8.23|install symfony/process v2.8.24|install symfony/process v2.8.25|install symfony/process v2.8.26|install symfony/process v2.8.27|install symfony/process v2.8.28|install symfony/process v2.8.29|install symfony/process v2.8.3|install symfony/process v2.8.30|install symfony/process v2.8.31|install symfony/process v2.8.32|install symfony/process v2.8.33|install symfony/process v2.8.34|install symfony/process v2.8.35|install symfony/process v2.8.36|install symfony/process v2.8.37|install symfony/process v2.8.38|install symfony/process v2.8.39|install symfony/process v2.8.4|install symfony/process v2.8.5|install symfony/process v2.8.6|install symfony/process v2.8.7|install symfony/process v2.8.8|install symfony/process v2.8.9|install symfony/process v3.0.0|install symfony/process v3.0.0-BETA1|install symfony/process v3.0.1|install symfony/process v3.0.2|install symfony/process v3.0.3|install symfony/process v3.0.4|install symfony/process v3.0.5|install symfony/process v3.0.6|install symfony/process v3.0.7|install symfony/process v3.0.8|install symfony/process v3.0.9|install symfony/process v3.1.0|install symfony/process v3.1.0-BETA1|install symfony/process v3.1.0-RC1|install symfony/process v3.1.1|install symfony/process v3.1.10|install symfony/process v3.1.2|install symfony/process v3.1.3|install symfony/process v3.1.4|install symfony/process v3.1.5|install symfony/process v3.1.6|install symfony/process v3.1.7|install symfony/process v3.1.8|install symfony/process v3.1.9|install symfony/process v3.2.0|install symfony/process v3.2.0-BETA1|install symfony/process v3.2.0-RC1|install symfony/process v3.2.0-RC2|install symfony/process v3.2.1|install symfony/process v3.2.10|install symfony/process v3.2.11|install symfony/process v3.2.12|install symfony/process v3.2.13|install symfony/process v3.2.14|install symfony/process v3.2.2|install symfony/process v3.2.3|install symfony/process v3.2.4|install symfony/process v3.2.5|install symfony/process v3.2.6|install symfony/process v3.2.7|install symfony/process v3.2.8|install symfony/process v3.2.9
    - php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg v0.11.1 requires alchemy/binary-driver ^1.5 -> satisfiable by alchemy/binary-driver[1.5.0, 1.6.0].
    - alchemy/binary-driver 1.5.0 requires symfony/process ~2.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.x-dev, 2.1.x-dev, 2.2.x-dev, 2.3.x-dev, 2.4.x-dev, 2.5.x-dev, 2.6.x-dev, 2.7.x-dev, 2.8.x-dev, v2.0.10, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.38, v2.3.39, v2.3.4, v2.3.40, v2.3.41, v2.3.42, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.0-BETA1, v2.4.0-BETA2, v2.4.0-RC1, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.0-BETA1, v2.5.0-BETA2, v2.5.0-RC1, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.0-BETA1, v2.6.0-BETA2, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.0-BETA1, v2.7.0-BETA2, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.3, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32, v2.7.33, v2.7.34, v2.7.35, v2.7.36, v2.7.37, v2.7.38, v2.7.39, v2.7.4, v2.7.40, v2.7.41, v2.7.42, v2.7.43, v2.7.44, v2.7.45, v2.7.46, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.0-BETA1, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.34, v2.8.35, v2.8.36, v2.8.37, v2.8.38, v2.8.39, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
    - symfony/process 2.0.4 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process 2.0.5 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process 2.0.6 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process 2.0.7 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process 2.0.x-dev conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process 2.1.x-dev conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    ....
    ....
    .... Removed because of character limit
    .... 
    ....
    - symfony/process v3.1.0-RC1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.1.1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.1.10 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.1.2 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.1.3 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.1.4 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.1.5 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.1.6 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.1.7 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.1.8 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.1.9 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.2.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.2.0-BETA1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.2.0-RC1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.2.0-RC2 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.2.1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.2.10 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.2.11 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.2.12 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.2.13 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.2.14 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.2.2 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.2.3 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.2.4 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.2.5 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.2.6 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.2.7 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.2.8 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - symfony/process v3.2.9 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - Installation request for symfony/console (locked at v4.0.9) -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v4.0.9].
    - alchemy/binary-driver 1.6.0 requires symfony/process ^2.0|^3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.x-dev, 2.1.x-dev, 2.2.x-dev, 2.3.x-dev, 2.4.x-dev, 2.5.x-dev, 2.6.x-dev, 2.7.x-dev, 2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev, 3.1.x-dev, 3.2.x-dev, 3.3.x-dev, 3.4.x-dev, v2.0.10, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.38, v2.3.39, v2.3.4, v2.3.40, v2.3.41, v2.3.42, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.0-BETA1, v2.4.0-BETA2, v2.4.0-RC1, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.0-BETA1, v2.5.0-BETA2, v2.5.0-RC1, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.0-BETA1, v2.6.0-BETA2, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.0-BETA1, v2.7.0-BETA2, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.3, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32, v2.7.33, v2.7.34, v2.7.35, v2.7.36, v2.7.37, v2.7.38, v2.7.39, v2.7.4, v2.7.40, v2.7.41, v2.7.42, v2.7.43, v2.7.44, v2.7.45, v2.7.46, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.0-BETA1, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.34, v2.8.35, v2.8.36, v2.8.37, v2.8.38, v2.8.39, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9, v3.0.0, v3.0.0-BETA1, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.0-BETA1, v3.1.0-RC1, v3.1.1, v3.1.10, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.2.0, v3.2.0-BETA1, v3.2.0-RC1, v3.2.0-RC2, v3.2.1, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.14, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.3.0, v3.3.0-BETA1, v3.3.0-RC1, v3.3.1, v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.13, v3.3.14, v3.3.15, v3.3.16, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9, v3.4.0, v3.4.0-BETA1, v3.4.0-BETA2, v3.4.0-BETA3, v3.4.0-BETA4, v3.4.0-RC1, v3.4.0-RC2, v3.4.1, v3.4.2, v3.4.3, v3.4.4, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[3.3.x-dev, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[3.4.x-dev, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.0, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.0-BETA1, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.0-RC1, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.1, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.10, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.11, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.12, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.13, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.14, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.15, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.16, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.2, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.3, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.4, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.5, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.6, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.7, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.8, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.3.9, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.4.0, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.4.0-BETA1, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.4.0-BETA2, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.4.0-BETA3, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.4.0-BETA4, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.4.0-RC1, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.4.0-RC2, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.4.1, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.4.2, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.4.3, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.4.4, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.4.5, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.4.6, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.4.7, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.4.8, v4.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.4.9, v4.0.9].
    - Installation request for symfony/process (locked at v4.0.9) -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.0.9].


    Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

What should I do ?

### EDIT :

I found the solution and answered my Q

Comment: You could install the standalone Unix ffpmeg library and run de commands you need from Laravel

Comment: @Borjante thanks . I'd like to use this programmatically with this library but can u give some examples for ur solution?

Answer (score 1):

To install this package :

Add to your **composer.json**:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/BinaryDriver.git"
    }
],
```

run `composer require php-ffmpeg/binary-driver=dev-master`

run `composer require php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg`